# Best way to use Regex and int's

Tags: c#

I have an application that loops through a group of documents and if a value is detected, then the user receives a prompt to replace this value. My current code looks like the following;

```
if (alllines[i].Contains("$"))
{
    // prompt
    int dollarIndex = alllines[i].IndexOf("%");
    string nextTenChars = alllines[i].Substring(dollarIndex + 1, 18);
    string PromtText = nextTenChars.Replace("%", "").Replace("/*", "").Replace("*/", "");

    string promptValue = CreateInput.ShowDialog(PromtText, fi.FullName);

    if (promptValue.Equals(""))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        alllines[i] = alllines[i].Replace("$", promptValue);
        File.WriteAllLines(fi.FullName, alllines.ToArray());
    }
}
```

As you can see the prompt box displays 18 characters after the index which in this case is `%` however, if there are not 18 characters then the application crashes. What I want to do is use regex but I am unsure of how to apply this in the codes current state.

If I use the below I get the error `Cannot convert from int to string` any help would be appreciated.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\$.{1,10})");
var chars = regex.Matches(dollarIndex);
```

Comment: You can just replace `18` with `alllines[i].Length - dollarIndex`. The error is saying that you are passing `dollarIndex` which is the position of the `$` instead of the `alllines[i]`

Comment: Is it the last item on the line?  Or does it terminate with the space?  Try leaving out the length : Substring(dollarIndex + 1); which will get the rest of the line.

Comment: You should show us what a typical line could look like. You can probably do this without regular expressions. That being said, you are trying to match at the *integer index* of the “dollar” symbol. You probably want to match on the whole line: `regex.Matches(alllines[i])` – also note that `%` is not the dollar symbol; you probably meant to use `$` everywhere.

Comment: @Poke I have edited the question to show what a line should look like in the document I hope that help what I am trying to explain :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(/*%.{1,50})");
var chars = regex.Match(alllines[i]).ToString();

string promptValue = CreateInput.ShowDialog(PromtText, fi.FullName);
```